# SQL Server to MYSQL Migration tool

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

I want to migrate my SQL Server database into MYSQL. Is there any open source or free software for that?

Comment: How free and/or open source do you consider INSERT statements?

Comment: More than 6000 record.... i dont prefer these insert statements...:-)

Comment: Meh - done at least 1/4 of a million.  Just queue them up & get coffee.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late answer. just saw your post. what you can do is,

dump sql file from the table in MSSQL and use that file to import data into MySQL table. you can use navicat for this ( import to mySQL).

Answer (score 0):

There is the MySQL Migration Toolkit which is part of the MySQL GUI tools available at

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

It does require some configuration to get working, is a pain but does get the job done.

Comment: I just found a link that gives a guide to using it http://www.coderintherye.com/convert-mssql-to-mysql