# How to migrate from ms sql to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, database-migration

Is there any software that I could use to convert an ms sql database to mysql?
I tested exporting the ms sql database using ms sql server management studio. And imported sql file using phpmyadmin. But I got this error:

```
USE [students] GO /****** Object: Table [dbo].[student_info] Script Date: 05/29/2011 15:20:20 ******/ SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO CREATE TABLE [dbo].[student_info]( [idnum] [nchar](10) NULL, [fname] [nchar](10) NULL, [lname] [nchar](10) NULL, [course] [nchar](10) NULL, [address] [nchar](10) NULL ) ON [PRIMARY] GO
```

Please help,

Comment: Official docs: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/migrating-from-microsoft.html

Comment: Duplicate: [MSSQL to MYSQL Migration tool](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1442600)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSSQL to MYSQL Migration tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442600/mssql-to-mysql-migration-tool)

Comment: When you import with PHPMyAdmin, the latest version let's you choose compatibility type, e.g. MSSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously you cannot run just run plain T-SQL in a mysql database. Each database has it's own flavor of SQL. What you could do though is that you could pick a platform that support both databases and migrate the data by first loading pieces of it into a program.

However, mysql and SQL Server are very different databases and they support a very different set of features. First you should make sure that you actually can migrate because there are bound to be issues between the two databases that you haven't thought of.